# Execute a Node.js child process after clicking a button

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack, energyplus

At the moment I have a code in Node.js which calls the program "EnergyPlus". Unfortunately I have to start an external console and execute the Node.js file "manually". However, I would like to be able to press a button in the front end of my application that starts the "EnergyPlus" plus program.

Here is my Node.js file:

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn,
child = spawn('C:\\EnergyPlusV9-0-1\\EP-Launch.exe', ["C:/Windows/System32/Drivers/etc/hosts"]);

child.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
    console.log('stdout: ' + data);
});

child.stderr.on('data', function (data) {
    console.log('stderr: ' + data);
});

child.on('close', function (code) {
    console.log('child process exited with code ' + code);
});
```

Is there a way to integrate this code within a button or to execute this code after clicking a button? 
Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: I integrate react and webpack because I use those within my application.

Comment: I stuck with my research at the point, that I do not know how to integrate the child process within my react application.

Comment: Well you will need a server side part in order to execute this code. You are not able to directly run this kind of code from your front end.

Comment: An express server is running in the background. But how I can or should I integrate the node child process into it and how can I connect the express server with the front end in that way, that the EnergyPlus software will run?

Comment: You can achieve this when configuring an endpoint (route) on your express server and make AJAX request from react to this route, now you can invoke the upper code in this route handling function and return a response to react

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how you can do this:

1. On client side button click, make a request to a certain path in your express API
2. Your express API handles the request by launching the program

Code something that looks like this:

client.html:

```
<button onclick="func()">start app</button>
<script>
  const func = () => fetch('http://your.api.url/some/path');
</script>
```

server.js:

```
// imports
const express = require('express');
const spawn = require('child_process').spawn;

// create server
const app = express();

// upon request to the launch path, launch the program
app.get('/some/path', (req, res) => {

  let child = spawn(
    'C:\\EnergyPlusV9-0-1\\EP-Launch.exe',
    ["C:/Windows/System32/Drivers/etc/hosts"]
  );
  // etc (rest of the code you wrote)

  // response. You can modify this to send a custom response to your client
  res.send('');
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for the help!
I have found the solution for my problem.
To start from the beginning, within my application I work with React and Webpack. To solve my problem, I structured my Server.js file (where I set up the Express behavior) in the following way:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
const fs = require("fs")
const spawn = require('child_process').spawn;

// console.log that your server is up and running
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`));
app.use(cors())

// create a GET route
app.get('/express_backend/:filename', (body, res) => {
const f = body.params.filename;

// open EnergyPlus Programm with a specific file which is stored localy
let child = spawn(
'C:\\EnergyPlusV9-0-1\\EP-Launch.exe',
 [process.cwd()+"src/"+ f + ".idf"]
 );

child.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
console.log('stdout: ' + data);
});

child.stderr.on('data', function (data) {
console.log('stderr: ' + data);
});

child.on('close', function (code) {
console.log('child process exited with code ' + code);
});

res.send('EnergyPlus is running');
});

// default options
app.use(fileUpload());

//post the uploaded file into the local storage
app.post('/upload', function(req, res) {
  ...
}

// The name of the input field (i.e. "sampleFile") is used to retrieve the uploaded file
let sampleFile = req.files.file;

// Use the mv() method to place the file localy
 fs.writeFile(__dirname + `/upload/${sampleFile.name}`, sampleFile.data,
(err) => {
   ....
  })
});
```

Like Nino Filiu mentioned in his post, I integrated the child spawn function into the server.js. First, I call the EP launch.ex with the specific file, I stored localy (this function is not part of this answer). "C:\EnergyPlusV9-0-1\EP-Launch.exe"is the path to EnergyPlus. "[process.cwd()+"src/"+ f + ".idf"]" helps EnergyPlus to open the local stored fiel directl.
So the important thing regarding my problem was the app.get, which I trigger within my App.js.
In App.js I call the spawn child process like this:

```
class App extends Component { 

constructor(props){
super(props)
this.state = {filename: null}
};

componentDidMount() {
  ...
};

callBackendAPI = async () => {
  ...
};

//trigger the spawn child function within server.js
startEnergyPlus = (e) =>{
fetch (`http://localhost:5000/express_backend/${this.state.filename}`, {
method: "GET"
});

render(){
 return( 
  <div className="App">
   <button onClick={this.startEnergyPlus}>start app</button>
  </div>
};
```

And that is it. Hopefully, it is clear and helpfull. If not, please leave a comment!